# Undefined variable inside of foreach

Tags: php, function

I can not figure out why this is happening the following is my code. I am suspecting it has something to do with scope however I can var_dump $items just fine.

```
<?php
/*
* Setup the API scripts.
*/
require (dirname(__FILE__).'/vesu/SDK/Gw2/Gw2SDK.php');
require (dirname(__FILE__) .'/vesu/SDK/Gw2/Gw2Exception.php');

use \vesu\SDK\Gw2\Gw2SDK;
use \vesu\SDK\Gw2\Gw2Exception;
// Request a new instance of the API
$gw2 = new Gw2SDK(dirname(__FILE__).'/cache/items/', 604800);

// End of code header
function refreshCache($gw2){
    $i=0;
    $items = $gw2->getItems();
    #var_dump($items);
    foreach($items as $itemId){
        var_dump($itemsId);
        $item = $gw2->queryItemDetails($itemId);
        var_dump($item);
        $itemName = $item->name;
        echo "writing " . $itemId . "," . $itemName . "to the cache";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "Added " . $i . " Items to the cache.";
}
refreshCache($gw2);
?>
```

Comment: `$itemsId` != `$itemId`

Comment: Just mistyped what @Boann commented

Comment: Well, in PHP you ***only*** get an undefined variable warning ***if*** and ***only if*** that variable actually is *undefined*. You still have objections that the variable is not undefined?

Comment: Do you have any debugging information about which line it has a problem with? My guess is perhaps you give $itemName an undefined value?

Comment: @user2532739: That would give an undefined property warning in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the help. var_dump($itemsId); was originally test code. I was having a problem with the actual function. Must have corrected it so many times that it actually was typed correctly when I posted this.

Comment: @hakre really? Not saying I doubt you, but I would expect it only to give you are warning if `$item` were undefined, not `$item->name`. Could you clarify which way it works?

Comment: @user2532739: https://eval.in/private/d11b445a206c52 you mean such?

Comment: @hakre Interesting, thank you!

Comment: @user2532739: This is similar to missing array indexes: https://eval.in/private/1639cdc1febc59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `var_dump($itemsId);`.

Your foreach loop is `$itemId` (no s at the end!)

EDIT: sorry, didn't see it was answered!

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake when you copied over your debug code:

```
var_dump($items);
```

to the second place where you then turned it into:

```
var_dump($itemsId);
              ^- copied but forgotten to remove "s" from earlier
```

So next time you copy and paste code you need to take more care. Learn from your own mistakes into which problems you tend to walk.

And `var_dump()` stinks for debugging, use a step debugger and unit-tests instead.